# Iterate through a json list with dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file which contains a list with many dictionaries. Here I've included just two. But I want to iterate through all of the dictionaries and only get the code value (Company1 and Company2).

```
[{"code":"Company1","exchange_short_name":"ST","date":"2000-01-01"},
{"code":"Company2","exchange_short_name":"ST","date":"2000-01-01"}]
```

I've gotten to this, but it gives me all of the values inside the dictionary, and not the code values.

```
for d in jsonData:
   for key in d:
       print(d[key])
```

Comment: What is `jsonData`? Please add the respective code for reading the json file.

Comment: jsonData is a variable name where I store all the data I'm getting through the API I'm calling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[item['code'] for item in jsonData]
```

will return list of codes.